# React: usestate and tab behaviour issue

Tags: reactjs

One of my current projects is learning React and coding in general by analyzing and playing with specific code fragments.
But now I'm stuck. I think I know what the problem is, but I can't solve it.

I have 2 tabs. Tab 1 is set as active, so it's content is shown if i vist the site. Tab 2 is set as inactive. If I click on Tab 2, the state is simply switched. This works.
But if I add a third tab as in this example, the behaviour get's weird.
If I click on Tab 2, Tab 3 is set as active as well and both contents are shown.

I would really appreciate some help. I don't want to give up understanding this.

Thanks!

```
const [main__tab_state, set_main__tab_state] = useState(true);

<div className="main__tab">
        <div className="page__flex">
          <div className="main__tab--box">
            <div className="main__tab--head">
              <ul>
                <li className={main__tab_state ? "active" : ""}>
                  <a className="js-tab" data-tab="tab" onClick={() => set_main__tab_state(true)}>TAB NAME 1</a>
                </li>
                <li className={main__tab_state ? "" : "active"}>
                  <a className="js-tab" data-tab="tab1" onClick={() => set_main__tab_state(false)}>TAB NAME 2</a>
                </li>
                <li className={main__tab_state ? "" : "active"}>
                  <a className="js-tab" data-tab="tab2" onClick={() => set_main__tab_state(false)}>TAB NAME 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="main__tab--box">
            <div className="main__tab--body js-tab__body">
              <div id="tab" className={`main__tab--item${main__tab_state ? "active" : ""}`}>
                <div className="text">
                  <p>
                    TAB TEXT 1
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="tab1" className={`main__tab--item${main__tab_state ? "" : "active"}`}>
                <div className="text">
                  <p>
                  TAB TEXT 2
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="tab2" className={`main__tab--item${main__tab_state ? "" : "active"}`}>
                <div className="text">
                  <p>
                  TAB TEXT 3
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = useState(0);` instead.

Then just kodify your code like so:

```
<a className="js-tab" data-tab="tab" onClick={() => setActiveTabIndex(0)}>TAB NAME 1</a>

<div id="tab" className={`main__tab--item${activeTabIndex === 0 ? "active" : ""}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change your state.

```
const [main__tab_state, set_main__tab_state] = useState("tab1"); // change state to store string values and default we will store tab1
```

Change your code to render tabs and content like below:-

```
<div className="main__tab">
        <div className="page__flex">
          <div className="main__tab--box">
            <div className="main__tab--head">
              <ul>
                <li className={main__tab_state === "tab1" ? "active" : ""}>
                  <a className="js-tab" data-tab="tab" onClick={() => set_main__tab_state("tab1")}>TAB NAME 1</a>
                </li>
                <li className={main__tab_state === "tab2" ? "" : "active"}>
                  <a className="js-tab" data-tab="tab1" onClick={() => set_main__tab_state("tab2")}>TAB NAME 2</a>
                </li>
                <li className={main__tab_state === "tab3" ? "" : "active"}>
                  <a className="js-tab" data-tab="tab2" onClick={() => set_main__tab_state("tab3")}>TAB NAME 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="main__tab--box">
            <div className="main__tab--body js-tab__body">
              <div id="tab" className={`main__tab--item${main__tab_state === "tab1" ? "active" : ""}`}>
                <div className="text">
                  <p>
                    TAB TEXT 1
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="tab1" className={`main__tab--item${main__tab_state === "tab2" ? "" : "active"}`}>
                <div className="text">
                  <p>
                  TAB TEXT 2
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="tab2" className={`main__tab--item${main__tab_state  === "tab3" ? "" : "active"}`}>
                <div className="text">
                  <p>
                  TAB TEXT 3
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Not really understand why you have to save tab name, when you can use tabIndex to check which tab is opened. 

const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(0); //flag for the 0index tab

//somewhere in the code 
if(tab == 0) {
 apply this style
} else {
...
}

Comment: I think it's more readable to use tab name instead of index. I think there are many approach to solve different problems. so whichever is best fit to developer, they can use it.